# What is the function to detect if parent/child node was pressed in ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to create an expandable list, where data is retrieved from the database. I'm using [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView). I'm coming from the Javascript world where we can [catch an event on click](https://jsfiddle.net/t4jqtLas/) and retrieve data, so I'm trying to do something similar in Java. For parent nodes, I'm thinking to use `HashMap<Integer, String> listTitle;` where `key` is a unique id, and `String` is the title.  When the user presses one of these titles, the list should expand under that title and I need to somehow "grab" that id from `HashMap`, make a SQL query, and return the results (as a `List<String>`) where id is the same, as a child node of that pressed parent.
Something similar to this:

```
List<String> listDetails = parentNode.onClick({
    return "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE id = " + parentNode.id;
})
```

The above code is definitely not runnable (just my form of pseudocode), so when `parentNode is pressed -> get the id -> make a SQL query -> the result is returned and stored in listDetails -> a list is expanded under a parentNode and displays all data in listDetails`

I went through documentation but didn't get much from that.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Are you trying to get the child data after the parent is clicked? If so then this is not a good practice all data in list view is generally fetched before hand since that in turn is used by the adapter to display the view. If you go by this there will be terrible lag on the UI let alone the issues you will face while coding this. If you have a lot of data which you do not want all to be loaded at a given time then you can use paging but have all data prefetched before allowing user clicks

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh yes.

Comment: I have two tables in database. One is stores unique id with titles. This is to display parentNodes. Second table is to store children of those titles. Same it has an id and names, but here the id is not unique, it can be duplicated

Comment: How would you suggest me to do it ?

Comment: You can create an ArrayList of All parent objects. Parent object can have a list of child objects this entire parent list can then be fed to the Adapter that you wrote for the Expandable list view. If the data is too large say more than 100 parents each having even more children then you can split the list into smaller groups say show only first 20 parents with children then if user scrolls to the end of list load the next set of 20 parents and append the array list.

Comment: If you are fetching this data from remote server instead of local DB on android then when user scrolls to the bottom hit the next api request

Comment: If all this data is from a local DB make sure the SQL queries run on background thread thus avoiding lag on UI

Comment: @TaranmeetSingh Yeah right, the problem is I don't know how to associate children with the parent objects. In DB each child record has its associate id to its parentNode

Comment: then maybe you can change the db structure to include some key in child table that helps in identifying all child of a parent